# This particular way of using .map() in python

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I was reading an article and I came across this below-given piece of code. I ran it and it worked for me:

```
x = df.columns
x_labels = [v for v in sorted(x.unique())]
x_to_num = {p[1]:p[0] for p in enumerate(x_labels)}

#till here it is okay. But I don't understand what is going with this map. 
x.map(x_to_num)
```

The final result from the map is given below:

```
Int64Index([ 0,  3, 28,  1, 26, 23, 27, 22, 20, 21, 24, 18, 10,  7,  8, 15, 19,
            13, 14, 17, 25, 16,  9, 11,  6, 12,  5,  2,  4],
           dtype='int64')
```

Can someone please explain to me how the `.map()` worked here. I searched online, but could not find anything related.
ps: df is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look what `.map()` function in general does in python.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(map(str, l))
# ['1', '2', '3']
```

Here the list having numeric elements is converted to string elements.
So, whatever function we are trying to apply using `map` needs an iterator.
You probably might have got confused because the general syntax of map (`map(MappingFunction, IteratorObject)`) is not used here and things still work.

The variable `x` takes the form of `IteratorObject` , while the dictionary `x_to_num` contains the mapping and hence takes the form of `MappingFunction`.

Edit: this scenario has nothing to with `pandas` as such, `x` can be any iterator type object.

Comment: Why are we not taking `x_to_num.keys()` here? Isn't that gonna give the same result?